# .net linq to entities "not in" single query

Tags: .net, linq

Iam using linq to entities and I want to get all Users that haven't signed up for the class. This is what I did.

```
var classUsers = from cu in myEntities.ClassUsers
                         where cu.Class.ClassId == classId
                         select new
                         {
                             FirstName = cu.UserInfo.FirstName,
                             Id = cu.UserInfo.Id,
                             LastName = cu.UserInfo.LastName,
                             Select = new Boolean()
                         };

        var allUsers = from u in myEntities.UserInfo
                       select new
                       {
                           FirstName = u.FirstName,
                           Id = u.Id,
                           LastName = u.LastName,
                           Select = new Boolean()
                       };

        var availableUsers = allUsers.Except(classUsers).OrderBy(a=>a.FirstName);
```

Is there a way I can merge the first two queries into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it but this could be a lightweight solution.

```
myEntities.UserInfo.Except(myEntities.ClassUsers.Where(cu=> cu.Class.ClassID = classID)
.Select(cu=>cu.UserInfo)).Select(u=>Id = u.Id, FirstName = u.FirstName, LastName =   
                                 u.LastName, Select = new Boolean())
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I had to tweak it a bit to make it work.
var availableUsers = myEntities.UserInfo.Except(myEntities.ClassUsers.Where(cu => cu.Class.ClassId == classId).Select(cu => cu.UserInfo)).Select(u => new { Id=u.Id,FirstName=u.FirstName,LastName=u.LastName,Select =new Boolean() }).OrderBy(u=>u.FirstName);